# Adding a column with the row number to csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to change the last column of my csv file to contain the row number.

My input file looks like this

```
Soup that is too hot,1,
Space Jam on VHS,1,
Space muffins,1,
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
Soup that is too hot,1,
Space Jam on VHS,2,
Space muffins,3,
```

This is the code I have written so far:

```
import csv
inputfile = csv.reader(open('file.csv', 'r'))
outputfile = open("output_file.csv", 'w')
nr = 1
for row in inputfile:
    place = row[1].replace('1',str(nr))
    outputfile.write( place+'\n')
    nr += 1
```

If I change the row[0] to row[1], I only get the numbers, if I make it row[0], I don't see the columns.

Comment: What's the 1st line of the csv?

Comment: card, id,
Soup that is too hot,1,
Space Jam on VHS,1,
Space muffins,1,

Comment: Do lines end with comma? Please update your question with the exact lines as they appear on the file.

Comment: yes they do, its a csv file

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but have you considered using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import re

with open("csv_rename_lines.csv") as f, open("csv_rename_lines_new.csv", "w") as w:
    lines = list(f)
    w.write(lines[0]) # write headers to new file
    for n, l in enumerate(lines[1:], 1):
        w.write(re.sub(r"\d+,\s*$", str(n)+",\n", l))
```

---

```
card, id
Soup that is too hot,1,
Space Jam on VHS,2,
Space muffins,3,
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/72383eff33)